# Buenas practicas para guardar con SocketIO, ExpressJS y Mongoose

Tags: nodejs, express, mongoose, socket.io, buenas-prácticas

Tengo un proyecto en NodeJs y soy un poco nuevo usando SocketIO. quisiera saber su opinión.

Para el API Rest ocupo ExpressJs y Mongoose y también sirve conexiones con SocketIO

Por ahora todo el manejo de base de datos lo hago en un modulo de Persistencia, algo asi:

> Request ---> ExpressJS ---> Router ---> [Persistencia] ---> Mongoose

Ahora me surgió la necesidad de guardar en BD algunos datos que entran desde SocketIO.

**Mi pregunta es:**

¿Es mejor desde el socket hacer las peticiones a mi API?

o

¿Es preferible desde el socket ir directo al modulo de Persistencia?

o

De plano usar directamente Mongoose en mi socket

*De antemano, muchas gracias :)*

Comment: ***quisiera saber su opinión***, las preguntas basadas en opiniones terminan cerradas, por favor repasar [ask] y lo que dice el [help/dont-ask] sobre el tipo de preguntas que debemos evitar. Saludos

Comment: Este tipo de preguntas, las puedes realizar en el [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol) de [es.so]. Tienes la suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/chat) para entrar y preguntar alli. Saludos